# How to sort a MutableMap by object field with saving other object field as index?

Tags: android, sorting, android-studio, kotlin, mutable

I'm storing `JSON`-loaded objects in `MutableMap` to have ability of getting one object by it's key (came with id field in `JSON` `object`):

```
[{id: 1, name: "Red"}, {id: 2, name: "Green"}]
```

I'm using `id` as index and **want to sort** `MutableMap` by `name` for output.

Should I use separate containers for mapping and output, or it is possible to accomplish both with just one container?

Comment: So? Do you have a question? Have you encountered a problem with your solution? What was the problem? What solutions have you tried?

Comment: @voddan Yes, I'm asking for some hints: am I going the right way or I should use separate containers for mapping and output.

Comment: Oh, ok. You didn't ask that in the question, so I was confused. I added the "asking a question" part, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @voddan sure, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to sortByValue you can try,

```
private fun sortingByValue() {

        val map = hashMapOf<Int, String>()
        map.put(1, "Red")
        map.put(2, "Green")

        val result = map.toList().sortedBy { (_, value) -> value }.toMap()
        for (entry in result) {
            print("key : ${entry.key}")
            println("value : ${entry.value}")
        }
    }
```

---

- **map** is converted to a list using `toList()`.
- `sortedBy()` is used to sort the list by `value { (_, value) -> value}`.
  We use _ for key because we don't use it for sorting.
- we convert it back to map using `toMap()` and store it in result.

Comment: yes. Not such short way as I expected, but it works.

Comment: Instead of converting map to list one can just take its `entries` collection.

Comment: The conversion back to map is not need if all what's needed is to output the result.

Comment: yes, you are right but to understand properly i have given this solution